# Артефакты в коде

Tags: компиляция

После сборки выполняемого файла или библиотеки добавляет ли компилятор информацию о себе?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Да, обычно добавляет. Не всегда правда явную. Некоторые иструменты (к примеру PeID) могут распознать компилятор (иногда с точностью до билда), ориентируясь на особенности генерации кода.

**upd**
Microsoft известна тем, что добавляет в exe [несколько байт](http://ntcore.com/files/richsign.htm), о значении которых люди долго спорят. [Ещё](http://www.wasm.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=484684) немного.